# API gateway not invoking a chalice endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, chalice

I am trying to expose a very simple endpoint using chalice and deploy it to AWS Lambda (not using Chalice CLI though). Then I create the corresponding aws lambda function by zipping up the code and uploading it.
Then I create the api gateway manually  and point it to the Lambda, doesn't matter how hard I try, I can't make the Lambda API to get called.

Python code

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response, BadRequestError, ChaliceViewError, NotFoundError
app = Chalice(app_name='test-app')
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return {
        "hello world"
    }
```

Api gateway route

[image]

Output

```
url: https://lw751abcd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test
{"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":"Unknown request."}
```

What am I missing here ?

### UPDATE

updated my code to below but still doesn't work.

```
@app.route('/test/{proxy+}', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return {
    "isBase64Encoded": true,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": { "status": "200"},
    "multiValueHeaders": { },
    "body": {
        "hello world"
    }
}
```

Comment: If yo use proxy integration for lambda, you must use the following output [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).

Comment: @Marcin I have updated my output response but still it's not working. Please see the update on post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that while creating api gateway , I was choosing `HTTP` instead of `REST` as type.
With API type as `REST`, everything was working as expected and I didn't have to worry about request and response body.